# Using JQuery to .trigger('click') seems to unbind all actions for a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

I am in the middle of writing some unit tests for a modal component I am developing. When I got around to testing that the action buttons, deny and ok, called the correct handler when clicked.

I thought an easy way to do this would be to call jquery .click(), .trigger('click'), or .tiggerHandler('click') on the button elements.

However doing so seems to unbind the click handler for not only the button being clicked but also the other action buttons and the dimmer. Making the modal impossible to exit.

```
let myModal = $('#confirmModalPanel');
myModal
  .modal({
    closable: false,
    onDeny: function() {
      console.log('onDeny was called');
    },
    onApprove: function() {
      console.log('onApprove was called');
    }
  });

$('#btnReset').click(() => {
  myModal.modal('show');
});

// Cannot trigger deny action from click in code. 
// The first click correctly runs but seems to unbind the click event
// from the deny button and breaks the modal functionality. Commenting
// out these lines will make the modal behave normally. 
console.log('Trying to click the accept button from code');
$('#positiveButton').trigger('click');

console.log('Trying to click the deny button from code');
$('#denyButton').trigger('click');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TuckerD/fpt3rzkp/22/

Comment: https://semantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html  Seems to reflect that the classes should be `approve` not `positive`; and `cancel` not `deny`

Comment: https://semantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html#/settings

Can be any of deny, cancel, negative or ok, positive, approve. The modal works correctly if you do not try to trigger the actions in code with jQuery. Never-the-less, I tried changing the div classes to what you suggested and it did not change the behavior.